# How to share code between two angular project?

Tags: angular, deployment, build

I have two Angular projects. They will share some code like pipes, classes, utils, enums and so on.

They are now allowed to deploy to the public repository.

Also we don't have private repository.

I Knew maven can use install command to deploy builds into local maven repository.

Is it a good idea to let angular projects did the same way?

How do you share code between two angular projects in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple projects and libraries can share the same angular workspace. If you look at the [angular cli documentation](https://angular.io/cli/new):

> If you plan to have multiple applications in the workspace, you can create an empty workspace by setting the `--createApplication` option to false. You can then use `ng generate application` to create an initial application. This allows a workspace name different from the initial app name, and ensures that all applications reside in the `/projects` subfolder, matching the structure of the configuration file.

Then you can put your shared code into [libraries](https://angular.io/guide/libraries). You can create a library with `ng generate library` command.

Comment: Thanks! my projects already exist in the same git repo.  Is this your idea: link two projects in package on local relative path? How can I do it manually?

Comment: Easiest way would be creating a new workspace, creating applications via cli and copying existing code to the new workspace. It is explained in the documentation.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!